# Unable to select an option from right click menu in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to select an option (say 3rd) from the right-click menu options available when we right-click on a web page through the cursor. I am using the below code to achieve that but couldn't succeed.

Below is my code snippet. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```java
WebElement hotSpot = driver.findElement(By.id("hot-spot"));
System.out.println("Context menu case");
Actions click1 = new Actions(driver);
click1.contextClick(hotSpot).perform();
click1.contextClick(hotSpot).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the below snippet

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(hotSpot).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Comment: This is not working for my code. We need to first right the code for shifting the focus on right menu appearing, then only we can write the code for selecting any option from menu.